Upgrading libstdc++ to Include GLIBCXX_3.4.30 on Oracle Linux 9.4 AArch64 for Amazon Q Extension Compatibility
Has anyone successfully added GLIBCXX_3.4.30 to Oracle Linux 9 (specifically version 9.4 on AArch64 architecture)? I am encountering a version mismatch error when trying to run the Amazon Q extension on Visual Studio Insiders 1.93.0. The available libstdc++.so.6 on my system only goes up to GLIBCXX_3.4.29. What are the best practices or recommended steps to upgrade the libstdc++ library to include GLIBCXX_3.4.30, or is there an alternative workaround that you've found effective?
Request initialize failed with message: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found 
(required by /home/opc/.vscode-server-insiders/extensions/amazonwebservices.amazon-q-vscode-1.22.0/
resources/qserver/dist/build/Release/faiss-node.node)


Probably easier to build from source than trying to upgrade libstdc++ https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/tree/master/packages/amazonq
